# read long message from client

Tags: sockets, network-programming, malloc, buffer

I am trying to read a long message from the client then print to the server `stdout`, but when I run the code, the length of the data that is read from client is different almost every time...

I also tried using `malloc`, but the result was same. I'm really wondering why...

The client code is well made, the problem seems to be on the server side.

Here's the relevant part of the code:

```
char buf[MAX];    //MAX=1024;
memset(buf, '\0', sizeof(buf));
size_t b;

while ((b = read(connect_fd, buf, MAX - 1)) > 0) {
    buf[b] = '\0';
    printf("%s", buf);
    flush(stdout);
    write(coonect_fd, buf, strlen(buf));
    memset(buf, '\0', MAX);
}
```

Comment: There are no packets (or messages) at TCP level. There is a stream of bytes. You will read as much bytes out of kernel as circumstances allow. It is up to you app to split stream of bytes into messages. Basically at the start of the message (serialized structure) you would place some ID and length. And at receive side you could pre-allocate required amount of memory(according to ID/length) to receive an object in a number of sequential reads. btw, you do not need ```memset```

Comment: There is nothing anywhere in the documentation that says that `read()` fills the buffer.

Comment: How can I place ID and length...?

Answer (score 0):

This read loop seems OK, there could be problems somewhere else, in the server code or in the client code. Here are a few pointers to potential problems:

- There is no need to clear the array with `memset()`.
- `b` should be defined as `ssize_t` to detect `read` errors and avoid undefined behavior if `read()` returns `-1`.
- setting the null terminator is not strictly needed: you can use `printf("%.*s", (int)b, buf);` or `fwrite(buf, 1, b, stdout);`.
- when writing to the `coonect_fd`, use `b` instead of `strlen(buf)`.
- make sure the client flushes its output the socket.